# How to send message to individual client in node.js using only Net module(not socket.io)

Tags: sockets, node.js, chat

Simple code:

```
process.stdin.resume()
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
var server = createServer();
server.listen(9999);
server.on('connection',function(sock){
    console.log('CONNECTED:'+sock.remoteAddress+":"+sock.remotePort);
    process.stdin.on('data',function(send){
            sock.write(send);
    });
}
```

- When receiving connection from 10.10.10.1 and 10.10.10.2,
  message "CONNECTED:10.10.10.1:xxx" and "CONNECTED:10.10.10.2:xxx"
  are display on terminal
- To send message to a client, I used sock.write(send)..
  but, All clients received message
- How can I send a message to a specific client.
  From googling there are many socket.io related documents(solutions)..
  but, before using socket.io, I want to know node.js itself.
  (or javascript itself?)

---

- After reading Vadim's comment, I wrote down more code below.
  fully working code.
- I add two things. According to Vadim's comment, add property sock.id
  and using property sock.remoteAddress, send server's stdin message to
  10.10.10.1 client only

var net = require('net')
process.stdin.resume()
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
var server = net.createServer();
server.listen(9999);
server.on('connection',function(sock){
        sock.write('input your ID: ',function(){
                var setsockid = function(data){
                        id=data.toString().replace('\r\n','');
                        console.log('ID:'+id+' added!!')
                        sock.id=id
                        sock.removeListener('data',setsockid);
                };
                sock.on('data',setsockid);
                sock.on('data',function(data){
                        d=data.toString().replace('\r\n','');
                        console.log(sock.id+' say: '+d);
                });
        });
    console.log('CONNECTED:'+sock.remoteAddress+":"+sock.remotePort);
    process.stdin.on('data',function(send){
            if (sock.remoteAddress=='10.10.10.1') sock.write(send);
    });
});

Comment: Thanks for your edit...Writing code line like above was a little difficult for me because This was my first post

Answer (score 4):

Answer to your question is on [Node.JS main page](http://nodejs.org/).

```js
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
    socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: thanks!. I understand that "sock.pipe(socket)" make outstream of the socket pipe to input stream of the socket, and using this, server can send data from specific clients to that client only. But The thing I want to know is this... Is there any way to send A message(for example server's stdin) to A SPECIFIC CLIENT (in my example, to ONLY 10.10.10.1 client).

Comment: In this example socket.write send to specific connection only. Even if you create many connections from one address socket.write will send data to one connection only. You need additional authenticate clients because ip address is not identifies client.

Comment: Thanks Vadim. Client need to be authenticated. that's right. Server needs client's identification. I wrote more code. It is too difficult to write code in comment box, so please see original question.